# Книги по сетевому программированию

Tags: c, книги

Посоветуйте книги по сетевому программированию (Windows/Linux) на С++ ДЛЯ НАЧИНАЮЩИХ.
 Кто какие читал, какие понравились, какие нет?

Comment: Ну, например, третий том Камера: Камер, Стивенс. Сети TCP/IP. Разработка приложений.

А в Уолтон. Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux -- так сразу на C, C++ и java (это к Вашему предыдущему вопросу). А вообще имя таким книгам легион. Много их...

Comment: Под какую ОС?

Comment: @mikillskegg http://hashcode.ru/questions/285099/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

По **линукс** (POSIX) - однозначно книги У. Стивенс "UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений" и третий том Д. Камера (Сети TCP/IP)

По **винде** (WinSock) - однозначно Джонс , Оланд "Программирование в сетях Microsoft Windows" ну и MSDN ес-но.